# How to get formatted currency value for India?

Tags: java, formatting, format, currency, number-formatting

For example in USA 1000000 represented as 1,000,000 (1 million) but in India it is represented as 10,00,000 (10 lakh). For this I tried some methods

```
double value = 1000000d;
NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
System.out.println(numberFormatter.format(value));
            

NumberFormat deci = new DecimalFormat("#,##,##,###.##");
System.out.println("Decimal Format "+deci.format(value));

NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("INR"));
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);      
System.out.println(format.format(value));
```

But all these methods give an output as 1,000,000 but I require format 10,00,000. What do I need to change here?

Answer (score 1):

Java decimal formatter doesn't support groups From [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)  :

> The grouping separator is commonly used for thousands, but in some
> countries it separates ten-thousands. The grouping size is a constant
> number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 3 for
> 100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000. If you supply a pattern with
> multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and
> the end of the integer is the one that is used. So "#,##,###,####" ==
> "######,####" == "##,####,####".

You will need another library for this. Suggest this :
http://site.icu-project.org/
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j/69.1

Code

```
double value = 1000000d;
NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
System.out.println(numberFormatter.format(value));
```

Output :

```
10,00,000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String fmt(String s)
{
    String formatted = "";
    if(s.length() > 1){
        formatted = s.substring(0,1);
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    
    while(s.length() > 3){
        formatted += "," + s.substring(0,2);
        s = s.substring(2);
    }
    return formatted + "," + s + ".00"; 
}
```